# Bash Script Variable Substitution

Tags: linux, bash, variables, substitution

I'm trying to combine some text to a variable and output the value of the combined variable.  For example:

```sh
testFILE=/tmp/some_file.log
function test_param {
echo $1
echo test$1
echo $(test$1) #this is where I want to output the value of the combined variable
}

test_param FILE
```

Output would be:

```
FILE
testFILE
/tmp/some_file.log  <-- this is what I can't figure out.
```

Any ideas?

If I'm not using the correct terminology please correct me.

Thanks,
Jared

Comment: @bitbucket where is it outputting to?  Or what's the output that I'm getting?

Comment: To expect a correct answer you need to supply the incorrect answer as a clue.  Are you getting any output?

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean this:

```
#!/bin/bash

testFILE=/tmp/some_file.log
function test_param {
echo $1
echo test$1
eval "echo \$test$1"
}

test_param FILE
```

output:

```
FILE
testFILE
/tmp/some_file.log
```

Comment: That's it. I knew there had to be a way to do it without using variables.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
testFILE=/tmp/some_file.log
function test_param {
    echo $1
    echo test$1
    varName=test$1
    echo ${!varName}
}

test_param FILE
```

The `!` before `varName` indicates that it should look up the variable based on the contents of `$varName`, so the output is:

```
FILE
testFILE
/tmp/some_file.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
testFILE=/tmp/some_file.log
function test_param {
    echo $1
    echo test$1
    foo="test$1"
    echo ${!foo}
}
```

`${!foo}` is an indirect parameter expansion. It says to take the value of `foo` and use it as the name of a parameter to expand. I think you need a simple variable name; I tried `${!test$1}` without success.

Answer (score 1):

Use `${!varname}`

```
testFILE=/tmp/some_file.log
function test_param {
    local tmpname="test$1"
    echo "$1 - $tmpname"
    echo "${!tmpname}"
}

test_param FILE
```

Output for that:

```
FILE - testFILE
/tmp/some_file.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  I both outputted the result, and stashed it as another variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

function concat
{
    echo "Parameter: "$1

    dummyVariable="some_variable"

    echo "$1$dummyVariable"

    newVariable="$1$dummyVariable"

    echo "$newVariable"
}


concat "timmeragh "

exit 0
```

The output was:

```
Parameter: timmeragh
timmeragh some_variable
timmeragh some_variable
```